# Looking for substantial open source GWT/App-Engine project to use as reference

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source, gwt

I'm working on GAE-J/GWT app, wherein a desktop app connects to the GAE-J component, and there is also a web-app component whose front-end is written in GWT, and the GAE-J backend supports both the desktop app and the web app.

I have a good amount of experience with writing pure server code and desktop code, but not so much on the web-app side of things.  So I'm looking to study some good sophisticated open source code to see how other's have done things, but I can't find much open source GWT and/or GAE-J stuff, other than frameworks.  Does anyone know of any good projects out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe that can help you http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Comment: This, in addition to the talk here: http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html is really eye-opening, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've written a little app called [SixFixMix](http://code.google.com/p/sixfixmix/) that uses the following stack: [GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/), [GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/), [dyuproject](http://code.google.com/p/dyuproject/) (for OpenID), [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) (for HTML5 Geolocation), [gwt-google-apis](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/) (for Maps), [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/), [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/), [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/), [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), and [GAEJ](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any GWT in it (yet?) but [Partychat](http://partychapp.appspot.com/) ([Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/partychapp)) is a moderately-sophisticated open-source Java App Engine app that simulates multi-user chatrooms using the XMPP service.

I'm sure there are more sophisticated apps out there, and some that include a GWT component, but I figured I'd take the chance to self-promote when it's given :)

Answer (score 2):

[GWT tagged](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:GWT) open-source projects on google code hosting.